# creating jquery ui tabs with jade(nodejs template engine)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, node.js, jquery-ui-tabs, pug

Hi I tried creating jquery ui tabs with jade template engine for node js, and it does not work.

here is the index.jade:

```
doctype 5
html
  head
    link(href='/stylesheets/style.css', rel='stylesheet')
    script(src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.1.min.js')
    script(src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.js')    
    script(src='/js/jquery-main.js')

body
#chat
  #nickname
    form.wrap#set-nickname
      p Please type in your nickname and press enter.
      input#nick
      p#nickname-err Nickname already in use
  #connecting
    .wrap Connecting to socket.io server
  #tabs
    ul
      li.first
        a(href='#grchat') group chat
      li.last
        a(href='#canv') canvas  
    #grchat
      #messages
        #nicknames
        #lines
      form#send-message
        input#message
        button Send
    #canv
      h1 example
```

and here is the jquery-main.js

```
$(function() {
  $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
});
```

the tabs are not rendered.

the rendered html is at: http://jsfiddle.net/Nfcfc/

Comment: what is the empty script tag for? and why do you nest your body into the head? also it seems you've put the other divs into the tabs div

Comment: ignore them as typos, my mistake.

Comment: hard to help you then, why dont you post the real html?

Comment: no. you posted your jade file which is only a template, it still compiles as "regular" html.

Comment: i have edited, please ignore indentation in the above code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't appear to be including a jQuery UI stylesheet, unless it's pasted inside your /stylesheets/style.css

To go with the example code you have posted, you need to add this to your template under the head:

```
link(href='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css', rel='stylesheet')
```

Without the jquery UI CSS, the tabs won't appear to render.

Comment: silliness on my part, too bad for me :( :(